# An application named "DNG converter just popped onto my screen and I don't remember installing it

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall

I would like to know what the application 'DNG Converter' is and what it does and why it popped up suddenly without me starting it? And if I don't need it, can I uninstall it? I cannot find it in synaptic.

Here is a screenshot of the application:

[image]

Comment: It's in the software center repos, according to this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/194998/518562

Comment: Did you recently install any KDE application such as `k3b`, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application `dngconverter` is part of the KDE `kipi-plugins` package. This a package of several applications that aim to extend the capabilities of image manipulation under KDE.

The [role of the DNG Converter](https://userbase.kde.org/Raw_to_DNG) is to convert RAW image files to the DNG or 'Digital Negative Format' of Adobe.

Actually you have picked up *several applications* along with the DNG Converter; the kipi (KDE Image Plugin Interface) plugins package comes with the following applications:

```
/usr/bin/dngconverter
/usr/bin/expoblending
/usr/bin/panoramagui
/usr/bin/photolayoutseditor
/usr/bin/scangui
```

The fact that you have inadvertently installed the DNG Converter is *undoubtedly* a result of a tangle of interrelated packages that came with a KDE application that you have installed. By themselves they could simply be left as is or you could see how many packages Ubuntu wants to remove when you run:

```
sudo apt-get remove kipi-plugins
```

If the package management system wants to remove too much simply allow this package and its associated applications to lie dormant on your computer...

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Packages: kipi plugins filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/kipi-plugins/filelist)
- [Wikipedia: KDE Image Plugin Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Image_Plugin_Interface)
- [KDE Wiki: Convert RAW Files to DNG with DNGConverter](https://userbase.kde.org/Raw_to_DNG)